# Reading raster attribute table using gdal in python

Tags: python, gdal

Is there a GDAL function that can read in a raster attribute table? Something functionally similar to this function in pygeoprocessing:

```
pygeoprocessing.geoprocessing.get_rat_as_dictionary_uri(dataset_uri)
Returns the RAT of the first band of dataset as a dictionary.

Parameters: dataset – a GDAL dataset that has a RAT associated with the first band
Returns:    value – a 2D dictionary where the first key is the column
name and second is the row number
Return type:    dictionary
```

Comment: RFC40 for enhanced RAT capabilities https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc40_enhanced_rat_support has these Python tests as an attachment https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/attachment/wiki/rfc40_enhanced_rat_support/rfc40_tests_hfa.py. Perhaps studying the tests can help you. There may be more Python tests in GDAL autotests https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/autotest